# Setting the "Title" property of an excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

First of all, I'm a total Excel interop noob.

I'm trying to get a date from a cell and then set the title of the document before the document gets saved, to be the month of the date. This is my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
   ThisWorkbook.Title = DateTime.Month(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cell("A10"))
End Sub
```

I'm not sure that anything is working. I set a breakpoint on the code, but I can't "run" it because it's not a macro, but an event handler, so I don't think the breakpoint is going to work. I don't get any errors. I don't even know that `ThisWorkbook.Title` is what I want and I'm not even sure about getting the month from the cell.

Comment: What do you want the result of the macro to be?  Are you trying to change the file name of the saved document?

Comment: So you just want the month portion of the date located in cell A10? What format is the date in?, i.e. MM/DD/YY or ?

Comment: @jbarker2160 @DyRuss Cell A10 has the date. It's just the cell where the user enters the date in the spreadsheet. When you go to the `File` menu in Excel, on the right side of the page is a list of `Properties`. I want the `Title` property to contain the text of the month from the date in the cell. So if the cell is `8/15/2014`, I want the `Title` property to be set to `August`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of the document is a "Built In" property - this is the info that appears when you right click on the file and look at the properties.
[image: Propery page of excel sheet]

The name of the spreadsheet is set on save, so you will want to save the file with a new name if you want to see the date on the file itself

A code something like this should give you the result you desire:
(note that this code is VBA, so it may need some tweaking to work in interop.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim FilePath As String
Dim varName As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

' This disables all Excel events.
Application.EnableEvents = False

' disable the default behaviour of the save like so:
Cancel = True

'you can leave this blank if you want it to save in the default directory
FilePath = "C:\The path\To\The File"

varName = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cell("A10"),"mmmm")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath & varName & ".xlsx"

ErrorExit:
' This makes sure events get turned back on again no matter what.
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "No value submitted - File Not Saved"
Resume ErrorExit
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the `Title` being a "Built-in property." It's a property of office documents. Not all files. I don't care about the name of the file. I care about the `Title` property.

Answer (score 6):

To change the 'Title' built in property in Excel:

ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Title") = "My Title Name"

Answer (score 0):

I assume this would serve your purpose:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Application.Caption = MonthName(Month(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C10").Value))
End Sub
```

Another thing is:

This title would not be there next time you open the workbook. So:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Caption = MonthName(Month(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C10").Value))
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added these macros, but nothing happens. Title does not get set ever. As far as I can tell, the `Workbook_BeforeSave` and `Workbook_Open` events aren't getting called. I added a `MsgBox` call to the first line of the `BeforeSave`, but it never gets displayed.

Comment: where did you add these? should be added under **ThisWorkbook** in your vba project. i have tested these and found ok before posting.

Comment: Ah, that was the problem. Thanks. But the other issue is that what I want to set is `ThisWorkbook.Title`, not `Application.Caption`. If you'll make that correction, I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: there is nothing as `Thisworkbook.Title`. If you want to change the name of the workbook, then 'saveas' thing is what you need.

Comment: Create your `Workbook_BeforeSave` and add the line: `ThisWorkbook.title = "Test"`. You will notice that after you save your document, the "Title" property gets set to "Test". `Application.Caption` sets the title bar, which is NOT what I want.

Comment: oh my bad! Indeed I made a mistake by declaring a thing without good observation. confirming your statement.